# How do I handle changing obvious attributes like fill in renderlet when redraw triggers?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a bar chart. I want to change the fill of specific bars to red based on the value of their data.

I don't want there to be a "flash" when the chart redraws; I never want the user to see the original fill. So it makes logical sense to change the fill of the bars on pretransition so that the color is changed before the bar displays on screen. However, when I try to do this, the bars flash red as they are rendering, but transition back to blue again as they render, making them look exactly the same as the others by the time they finish rendering. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/incredi_imp/j5ukyv3c/). Essentially, I tried this:

```
barChart.on('pretransition', chart => {
  chart.selectAll('rect.bar').filter(d => d.data.value > 18)
  .attr('fill', 'red');
})
```

How can I get the bars to be red *while they are transitioning* as well as after they finish rendering? I tried repeating the code on the renderlet as well, but they still transition to blue during the transition, then flash back to red after the transition.

Also, I don't want to turn the transitions off altogether by something like this:

```
barChart.transitionDuration(0)
```

I want to see the bars grow, just have them be red the entire time.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the [colorAccessor](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colorAccessor__anchor) and [colors](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colors__anchor) scale in order to color the bars, rather than trying to change them after the fact?

Comment: I guess this is integral to my question and I should have therefore included it, but I am actually trying to re-fill the bars with an svg pattern, not a solid fill. In order to create the pattern, I have to select the svg in which the chart is contained and add the pattern to the defs of that svg, but the svg doesn't get rendered until the chart is rendering, so I have to do that in pretransition--right?

Comment: That sounds really cool. Could you edit your question and fiddle to reflect what you're really trying to do? That will help others a lot, whereas answering the current question would only mislead people.

Comment: Thinking about it further, I don't think you'll run into any interference adding an svg pattern during `pretransition`, as you suggest, since dc.js doesn't use these attributes. Just do the old `defs.selectAll('#pattern').data([0]).enter().append...` trick to only add to the defs once, and then change the attributes on the bars at will. If you still want to change the colors or anything else that dc.js controls, there are ways - IIRC you just start another transition to cancel the old one. I can dig up an old question where I did that.